# Prove continuity for a given norm

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces

I struggle with this exercise from an analysis 2 book I use for self study:

> Let V := $C^1([0,1]; \mathbb{C})$ the vector space of continously differentiable functions from $[0,1]$ to  $\mathbb{C}$
>
> > 1.) Prove that map $f \mapsto \int_0^1 |f'(t)|dt +|f(0)|$ describes a norm.
> >     2.) Prove that the map $H\mapsto \mathbb{C} ; f \mapsto f(1)-f(0)$ is continous when using the previously defined norm.

The first part is really easy to show, but I struggle with the second part.
I tried to prove it using the epsilon-delta criterium, so that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta> 0$ so that $|H(f)-H(g)|<\epsilon$ for $|f-g|<\delta$.
Using the given norm, the "distance" between two functions is defined as 
$|f(1)-g(1)|<\delta$.
I have problems using the norm on $H(f)$, as H maps to two values of f.     When inserting the map of H into the norm I dont know how to create $f'(t)$ or $f(0)$ as there is only the value $H(f)=f(1)-f(0)$ given, which isconstant and not dependent on a variable, $t$ in this case, which you can differentiate for.
It seems as I dont see something which is obvious, can somebody point me out on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, notice that $H$ is linear, so you only need to prove linearity at 0. And you have this inequality :

$$| H(f) | = |f(1) - f(0) | =  \left| \int_0^1 f'(t) dt \right| \leq \int_0^1 | f'(t) | dt \leq \| f\|$$

So clearly, $H(f) \to 0 $ when $f \to 0$ : $H$ is continuous at $0$, and by linearity, everywhere